# How to handle dashes route in laravel 5 for multiple parameter

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-5

This is my url structure

> http://example.com/embed-id-size
>
> http://example.com/embed-adsdfwer3-640x240

where size is optional parameter.

I coded in routes.php of laravel 5 like this.

```
Route::any('embed-{id}-{size?}',['uses'=>'Example@video','as'=>'embed']);
```

Above all working well no problem but problem comes when my id have already dash like this **adsdfw-r3**

http://example.com/embed-adsdfw-r3-640x240
http://example.com/embed-adsdfw-r3

above both url laravel route not working and route suppose there is three parameter.

And after many searches i found this `->where('id', '.*(?=-)')` i apply this to my route and its working good only when i give size to my url but size is an optional parameter after applying `->where('id', '.*(?=-)')` size becomes compulsory to give.

please help me how to solve this problem.

i hope u will understand my question.

Comment: I understand that this post is old (and for Laravel 5), but for anyone using newer versions (I'm using 8.x) `{size?}` works with or without the `-`, but will break if the user navigates to `/embed-123-` where the 'size' is null.

Answer (score 1):

You have no easy way to solve that actually, because of the dash in the id.

I would either make sure there is no dash or I would capture the whole thing `{id}-{size?}` and calculate later if there is a resolution in the end or not and which one is the id.

Comment: Yeah you can't really use `-` as your separator if it's a valid character in the id... maybe use `_` or `/` as the separator instead?

Comment: so what should i do please do some code and give me example

Comment: my id has 13 character

Comment: So you can probably solve it with where:
  where(['id' => '[a-z\-]{13}'], 'size' => '[0-9]+x[0-9]+') 

or something like it, I can not test it at the moment.